# What is the name of this GitHub Actions configuration format?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment, github-actions

In the description of [GitHub Action for Hugo](https://github.com/srt32/hugo-action) I see the following code snippet:

```
workflow "Hugo build" {
  resolves = [
    "Hugo Action",
  ]
  on = "push"
}

action "Hugo Action" {
  uses = "srt32/hugo-action@master"
  needs = "Filters for GitHub Actions"
  args = "--theme=hyde-x"
}

action "Filters for GitHub Actions" {
  uses = "actions/bin/filter@b2bea0749eed6beb495a8fa194c071847af60ea1"
  args = "branch master"
}
```

In my project, I am using YAML for configuration, therefore I need to translate the above code into YAML. To do this, I need to know what this format/language is.

What is the name of the format in which the configuration above is written?

**Update 1:** According to [this](https://creativetechguy.com/utilities/codedetector) language identifier, it could be a [Nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf) config language.

**Update 2:** In [this article](https://jasonet.co/posts/what-are-github-workflows/) by [Jason Etcovitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5526745/jasonetco) I found code parts that look very similar to those in the GitHub action.

**Update 3:** Seems to be HCL, or [Hashicorp Configuration Language](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already found it was a subset of HCL ([Hashicop Configuration Language](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)). It was the language used for building actions during the beta before August 2019.

From the wayback machine, action format used to be like that before August 2019 :

[image]

In August 2019, the new YAML format was released:

[image]

[image]

In October 2019, HCL workflows [didn't work anymore](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-01-github-actions-hcl-workflows-are-no-longer-being-run/)

From [this old article](https://github.blog/2019-02-07-an-open-source-parser-for-github-actions/#the-actions-workflow-language) a presentation of the HCL workflow configuration language

> The Actions workflow language
>
> All main.workflow files are written in the Actions workflow language,
>   which is a subset of Hashicorp’s HCL. In fact, our parser builds on
>   top of the open source hashicorp/hcl parser.
>
> All Actions workflow files are valid HCL, but not all HCL files are
>   valid workflows. The Actions workflow parser is stricter, allowing
>   only a specific set of keywords and prohibiting nested objects, among
>   other restrictions. The reason for that is a long-standing goal of
>   Actions: making the Actions editor and the text representation of
>   workflows equivalent and interchangeable. Any file you write in the
>   graphical editor can be expressed in a main.workflow file, of course,
>   but also: any main.workflow can be fully displayed and edited in the
>   graphical editor. There is one exception to this: the graphical editor
>   does not display comments. But it preserves them: changes you make in
>   the graphical editor do not disturb comments you have added to your
>   main.workflow file.

It seems the migration guide from HCL to YAML is no longer available on help.github.com but the old site is available on the wayback machine[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191003081424/https://help.github.com/en/articles/migrating-github-actions-from-hcl-syntax-to-yaml-syntax). Bad news is that official migration repo has been removed,and the workflow-parser repo and hcl fork have also been removed completly

You can check [this](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-hugo) to build a Github Action workflow for Hugo